# Filter a Jquery Datable using a button

Tags: jquery

I have a datable that displays among others a field called Reference. I also have a news feed that displays the most recent entry, which also has the same reference field.

I'm looking for a solution, whereby, clicking on the hyperlink in the news feeds, will filter the datatable to only show that reference.

Is that even possible? if so, some example would be most welcome.

Regards

Jquery Code.

```
               $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
               $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);

               oTable = $('#tblMessageDetail').dataTable({
                   "aaData": dtDetailData,
                   "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, -1], [50, 100, "ALL"]],
                  // 'aStripClasses': null,
                   "iDisplayLength": 50,
                   //"aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
                   "bJQueryUI": true,
                   //"bAutoWidth": false,
                   //"bProcessing": true,
                  // "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
                   "sDom": 'RC<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',

                   "aoColumnDefs": [
                       {"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [11,12,13,14]}
                   ],

                  // "sDom": 'C<"top"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                   //"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                   //"bRetrieve": true,


                   //Scrolling .......
                   "sScrollY": "250px",
                   "sScrollX": "100%",
                   "sScrollXInner": "100%",
                   "bScrollCollapse": true,

                   //Dynamic Language .......
                   "oLanguage": {
                       "sZeroRecords": "There are no messages that match your search criteria",
                       "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page&nbsp;&nbsp;",
                       "sInfo": "Displaying _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
                       "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records",
                       "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                       "sEmptyTable": 'No Rows to display.....!',
                       "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
                   },
                   "oSearch": {
                       "sSearch": "",
                       "bRegex": false,
                       "bSmart": true
                   }

               });
```

and now the asp.net repeater:

```
<div class="module_content">
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSenderBIC" >
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="message">
<p><strong>Message Type:&nbsp;</strong><asp:Literal ID="ltMessageDetail" 
runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgType") %>'></asp:Literal></p>                               
<p><strong>Message Date:&nbsp;</strong><asp:Literal ID="ltMsgDate" 
runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgDate") %>'></asp:Literal></p>
<p><strong>Message Time:&nbsp;</strong><asp:Literal ID="ltMsgTime" 
runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgTime") %>'></asp:Literal></p>
<p><strong>Reference:&nbsp;</strong><a href="#"><asp:Literal ID="ltMsgRef" 
runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgRef") %>'></asp:Literal></a></p>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>                    
</div>
```

So, the Reference of the repeater is selected, it's value should be filtered in the datatable

Comment: Would you like a coffee with that?

Comment: Only if your offering Dead Man. :-)

Comment: Always post the code along with your problem here. Without code, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: OK. i'll go walk the dog and then post

Comment: ok, so here is the Jquery Code, which produces the table:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - sorted it. I had to use the event.preventDefault to stop the post back, and then used

```
 $("a").click(function(event){ oTable.fnFilter(this.innerHtml); });
```

just figure out how to reset the table now and jobs a good un

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with `.fnFilter()`.

http://datatables.net/ref

```
Filter the input based on data

$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sometime later - filter...
  oTable.fnFilter( 'test string' );
} );
```

I'm not clear on the HTML structure that you want to respond to (I don't know ASP at all), but something like this might be a start:

```
$('div.messages p:last-child a').click(function()
    {
    oTable.fnFilter("Reference");
    });
```

Comment: this isnt working. I think the href is forcing a postback of the page. I've replace the oTable.fnFilter("Reference") with an alert, and it doesnt fire.

Comment: Ok - sorted it. I had to use the event.preventDefault to stop the post back, and then used

   $("a").click(function(event){
     oTable.fnFilter(this.innerHtml);
    });

just figure out how to reset the table now and jobs a good un